# Does every n-chain have a homology class?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I was under the impression that not every (singular) $n$-chain has a homology class, since $H_n(X) = Z_n(X)/B_n(X)$, and not every $n$-chain is an $n$-cycle. But I came across the following in Rotman's text:

**Theorem 4.32.** *Let $X$ be a space. A 1-chain $\gamma = \sum_{i=0}^k m_i \sigma_i \in S_1(X)$ is a cycle if and only if $\gamma$ is homologous to a linear combination of polygons.*

This seems strangely worded to me. To even ask the question "is $\gamma$ homologous to a polygon?" don't we have to assume $\gamma$ is a cycle to begin with? How can we define a homology class for something that isn't necessarily a cycle? It seems to me that correct wording of the theorem should be:

"If $\gamma$ is a 1-cycle, then it is homologous to a linear combination of polygons."

Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: I would guess "homologous" then means in this context to "differ by an element in $B_n(X)$". I.e. the difference bounds.

Comment: Is this standard terminology in algebraic topology? Do you define the homology class of an arbitrary $n$-chain in $C_n(X)$ to be its image in $C_n(X)/B_n(X)$?

Comment: Quotient out $B_n(X)$ in $Z_n(X) \hookrightarrow C_n(X)$ and get an embedding of $n$-homology classes into $n$-chains mod boundary. The homology classes are the image. But in this way we can extend the relation of being homologous, which accounts to $a \sim a'\ in A$ iff $a-a'=0$ to  $A\subset B$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To sum up what I said in the comments: we want to characterize $n$-chains which are actually cycles. (by we I mean the theorem). (*)

In order to talk about chains to be "homologous" we don't require them to be actual homology classes, but extend the natural definition to chains. (**)

Now (*) and (**) imply that the theorem has the very right to exist and makes sense.